# SQL Procedure for duplicate handling

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got two tables and I need to implement some *duplicate handling*.
TableA got some duplicates and I want to remove the older one of the two entries. But if this older entry is not present in TableB it should be inserted in TableB before deletion in TableA.

I already managed to get the code to find all duplicates but I am currently struggling to solve the rest.

Here is my code to find all duplicates:

```
SELECT
    id,productnumber,
    MIN(init_ts) min_init, MAX(init_ts) max_init,
    COUNT(1) count
FROM
    TableA
GROUP BY
    id,productnumber
HAVING
    COUNT(1) > 1;
```

Now I have to check if the one with the older min_init is present in TableB or not. If present the record should be deleted from TableA, if not present the record should be inserted in TableB and afterwards deleted from TableA.

How could I achieve the described behavior?

Comment: Is this mysql or SQL server?

Comment: Can you please post both table structures, it would be easy for understanding.

Comment: They are exactly the same. TableA is filled with some etl load process. In this process some duplicates can be loaded into TableA which is why I need this duplicate check. TableB is just a backup table of TableA. Therefore if there are duplicates in TableA the old ones should be written into the backup table if not already present in the backup table and the newer one should be kept in TableA. Both have the relations id, productnumber,init_ts and some other columns which aren't of any interest for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Identify which rows you want to move. You can achieve this by identifying the latest row for each group(id, prodctnumber) by use of a max, and what you are left with are the old ones.

Example:

```
    SELECT product_id, MAX(timestamp_inserted) AS last_insert FROM table GROUP BY 1; 
    -- last entries
```

2. Create/insert to the history table

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE history_table;
SELECT * FROM table
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT product_id, MAX(timestamp_inserted) AS last_insert FROM table GROUP BY 1) AS last
on last.product_id=table.product_id AND last.last_insert=table.timestamp_inserted -- Join the latest rows to identify them
WHERE last.product_id is NULL -- select only the non-latest rows.
```

3. Delete your old values

> ```
> DELETE table 
> FROM table
> LEFT JOIN 
> (SELECT product_id, MAX(timestamp_inserted) AS last_insert FROM table GROUP BY 1) AS last
> ON last.product_id=table.product_id AND last.last_insert=table.timestamp_inserted -- Join the latest rows to identify them 
> WHERE last.product_id IS NULL --delete only the non-latest rows.
> ```

Comment: this is for mysql, as part the original tag. for SQL server, the delete and create table syntax may be slightly different.

Comment: could you please have a look at this again ? I do not have any product_id but id and productnumber which identifies the record. also if i run your query with my columns (`select id, productnumber,...`) I get 'id must also appear in Group By'.

Comment: regarding 'id must also appear in Group By', group by both columns and not just one.

Comment: Please update your answer to correct the queries concerning my use case so i can  your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the count of records is not great I would probably just combine the two table sets then remove the duplicates; it is easier than comparing between two sets.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following simple example of a list of characters:

```
A  
A  
B  
B  
C  
D  
D  
E
```

Let's put this into a table. This example creates a table variable.

```
declare @AlphaList table (AlphaKey char);  

insert into @AlphaList(AlphaKey) values ('A');  
insert into @AlphaList(AlphaKey) values ('A');  
insert into @AlphaList(AlphaKey) values ('B');  
insert into @AlphaList(AlphaKey) values ('B');  
insert into @AlphaList(AlphaKey) values ('C');  
insert into @AlphaList(AlphaKey) values ('D');  
insert into @AlphaList(AlphaKey) values ('D');  
insert into @AlphaList(AlphaKey) values ('E');  



select AlphaKey from @AlphaList order by 1;
```

If we now use the ROW_NUMBER function we can get a listing of @AlphaList table with a sequential list of row numbers.

```
select   
 ROW_NUMBER() over (order by AlphaKey) as RowNumber  
, AlphaKey  
from @AlphaList;  

1 A  
2 A  
3 B  
4 B  
5 C  
6 D  
7 D  
8 E
```

Now if we add RANK onto this query, we get an additional column ranking the data. For example, the values of 'A' are assigned a rank of 1 as they are equal, the values of B are assigned the next rank, C the next, etc. This is a simple way of assiging a value by class or category depending on how we order the data - the rank value of 3 simply means that all data with this rank number is the same.

```
select   
 RANK() over (order by AlphaKey) as Rank  
, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by AlphaKey) as RowNumber  
, AlphaKey  
from @AlphaList;  



1 1 A  
1 2 A  
3 3 B  
3 4 B  
5 5 C  
6 6 D  
6 7 D  
8 8 E
```

From this you can see that the first rows containing the AlphaKey column values of 'A', 'B' and 'D' have the same values generated by the RANK and ROW_NUMBER functions giving us a very simple way of deduplicating the data.

What is happening is that the data is now being ordered and classified or categorised simultaneously so that equal values are adjacent to each other. It all works because the 'order by' clauses are used to bring the data back as a specific sorted list the ROW_NUMBER function allocates sequential numbers to each row of data the RANK function allocates a value to each block of data matching the order criteria

```
with AlphaRank(Rank, RowNumber, AlphaKey) as (  
select   
  RANK() over (order by AlphaKey) as Rank  
, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by AlphaKey) as RowNumber  
, AlphaKey  
from @AlphaList  
)  
select AlphaKey  
from AlphaRank  
where Rank=RowNumber  

A  
B  
C  
D  
E
```

Practical Example
This process was used to extract missing data from tables to enable an Item dimension table to be back filled from invoice/credit fact tables. A query was run to extract all the Item numbers that were missing from the Item table, for example:

```
select ItemNumber, UnitCost into MissingItems from SalesInvoices where   ItemNumber not in (select ItemNumber from dimItem)
```

This produces a table containing all the missing item numbers together with   their unit cost. A similar query was run against the 'SalesCredits' table to   obtain further rows of data. The extracted data could look something like this:

```
777 10.10  
777 11.11  
777 12.12  
888 13.13  
888 14.14  
888 15.15  
999 16.16  
999 17.17  
999 18.18
```

The following code could then be run to deduplicate the data and, in addition, obtain the lowest unit price for the item number.

```
with GetMissingItems(Rank, RowNumber, ItemNumber, UnitCost) as (  
select   
  RANK() over (order by ItemNumber, UnitCost) as Rank  
, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ItemNumber, UnitCost) as RowNumber  
, ItemNumber  
, UnitCost  
from MissingItems  
)  
select   
  ItemNumber  
, UnitCost  
from GetMissingItems  
where Rank=RowNumber  

777 10.10  
888 13.13  
999 16.16
```

Conclusion
This is a simple process to solve one of the most complicated tasks required of a DBA. It is also fairly well performing and my own test was to extract 8314 item numbers from an Invoice table containing more than 63 million rows of data in less than 3 minutes. It's simplicity lies in the fact that you only need to add a couple of lines to a SQL select statement together with the appropriate ordering in the ROW_NUMBER and RANK function to get a workable solution. If you write the query so it returns a list of primary keys then you have a method for deleting unwanted rows.

[Source](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Deduplicate/70499/)

Comment: I know you can't post comments. But this is not an answer!! Put sample code and then provide the link !!